# How to find the source code for clipboard:// protocol on rebol?

Tags: rebol

Usually to get the source code one can use source func_name but for a protocol like clipboard:// how to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at some of them using eg.

```
probe system/schemes/ftp
```

but others like clipboard:// are native and no source is available.

Comment: that's really really really really really really a pity :) Rebol only supports text it should support picture.

Comment: Sure, it has been long a source of frustration.

Have a look at this http://www.mail-archive.com/rebol-list@rebol.com/msg14996.html by Gregg Irwin.

Answer (score 1):

Rebol 3 is open source now. Start here: https://github.com/rebol/rebol

The cross-platform portion of the clipboard port scheme is in src/core/p-clipboard.c and the platform-specific parts are in files like src/os/win32/dev-clipboard.c though at the time of writing this answer only Win32 and Android (in a third-party build) have clipboard support.

Rebol 2 and earlier are unlikely to be open sourced, sorry.